# Iterate over String

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

So, I have this problem:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env groovy
    
    package com.fsfs.fdfs.fsf.utils
    
    class GlobalVars {
        // TEST-DEV
        static String MY_URL1 = "https://myurl.com"
        static String MY_URL2 = "https://:6443"
        static String MYURLS_TEST = "${MY_URL1} ${MY_URL2}"

}
```

So I want to iterate over my URLS depending on the environment.

For example: in this ENV is TEST, but could be DEV, PROD and so on

```
 for( Name in GlobalVars."MYURLS_${ENV}".split(/\s+/)) {

    }
```

I'm not sure how to achieve this.
Basically, I want to iterate over a variable with a dynamic name.
The variable contains at least 2 strings

Comment: "Basically, I want to iterate over a variable with a dynamic name. " - Do you mean you want to iterate over each of the characters in the `String` value?

Comment: "The variable contains at least 2 strings" - Each of your variables is 1 `String`.  You don't have any variables shown there which contain more than 1 `String`.  That could be done with a `List` or array or other structure, but you show only `String`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this...

```
class GlobalVars {
        // TEST-DEV
        static String MY_URL1 = "https://myurl.com"
        static String MY_URL2 = "https://:6443"
        static String MYURLS_TEST = "${MY_URL1} ${MY_URL2}"
}

String ENV = 'TEST'
for( name in GlobalVars."MYURLS_${ENV}".split(/\s+/)) {
    println name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into CharacterIterator methods current() to get the current character and next() to move forward by one position. StringCharacterIterator provides the implementation of CharacterIterator.

or for a simpler task can

Create a while loop that would check each index of the string or a for loop like this

```
 for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
 
            // Print current character
            System.out.print(str.charAt(i) + " ");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating Strings works out of the box in Groovy:

```
"bla".each{println it}
```

.each{} closure will go over all characters of the string.

Same can be achieved with a more classical for-loop:

```
for(c in "foo") println c
```

Either way should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what would be the benefit of making a space separated list of values just to parse it again. Seems easier with a map of lists.

```groovy
class GlobalVars {
    // TEST-DEV
    static String MY_URL1 = 'https://myurl.com'
    static String MY_URL2 = 'https://:6443'
    static Map MY_URLS = [
        'TEST': [
            MY_URL1,
            MY_URL2,
        ],
    ]
}
String ENV = 'TEST'
GlobalVars.MY_URLS[ENV].each {
    println it
}
```

No regex, no dynamically generated property names. If you want to avoid typos in the environment names you can put them into an enum.